# Xcode project: Library not found for -lmp3lame

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

This error occur after copy my project:

```
Ld /Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SmartEdu.app/SmartEdu normal armv7s

cd /Users/DBK/DEV/iOS/DaouIncube/KERIS/Source/code/trunk/app_binary/SmartEdu

setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0

setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/DBK/DEV/iOS/DaouIncube/KERIS/Source/code/trunk/app_binary/SmartEdu -F/Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Intermediates/SmartEdu.build/Debug-iphoneos/Device-SmartEdu.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/SmartEdu.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lxml2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework MediaPlayer -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MobileCoreServices -framework AVFoundation -lxml2 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -lIN3EbookEngine_device -framework SystemConfiguration -lmp3lame -lNssoAgent-device -lz -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Intermediates/SmartEdu.build/Debug-iphoneos/Device-SmartEdu.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/SmartEdu_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/DBK/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SmartEdu-aqcslncevdjpaygiwxdpftddysjb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SmartEdu.app/SmartEdu

ld: library not found for -lmp3lame
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

here is image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKMjr.jpg

Comment: you need to post your code and error with your question

Comment: The linker couldn't find mp3lame.

Comment: (Don't post imgur links -- copy/paste the error message into your question.)

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that you need to format your error correctly (at least put a code block around it or something), you may want to look into debugging error messages from LLDB (the debugger). A clang/linker error means that a certain file cannot be found when the project is compiling.

```
ld: library not found for -lmp3lame
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

^This is the error you should be paying attention to. It notes that the library is not found for -lmp3lame. This means at compile time, this library does not exist. It may not be included in the linked classes, it may not be included in the target your building out, you may not have directed the framework's search paths/header paths correctly. With the little information provided above, it could be a variety of things with this being your best answer.